# Javascript events - how to create and store a variable that should only be accessed by one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've got a bit of an issue with a script I'm playing about with. I'm trying to draw triangles that when you click on them "flip" around and change colour and if clicked again they revert to their initial state. The problem is I'm not sure where to set the `isflipped` variable.

Does anyone have any ideas/has anyone come up with a problem like this before? Here's what I have at the moment:

http://jsfiddle.net/hnqB6/17/

Comment: Perhaps put a class of 'isFlipped' on the canvas that is clicked. Everytime a click occurs on a canvas, check if there an isFlipped class, if there is, remove it, if there's not one, add it - this provide you a conditional hook to base your animation on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save values in a map with index of elements as key e.g.

```
var flipmap = {}
flimmap[index] = false

//later in click
flipmap[index] = !flipmap[index]
```

other alternative is to use [jquery data API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to attach data with elements e.g.

first init flipped value per element

```
jQuery.data($("canvas")[i], 'flipped', false)//not-flipped
```

than on click toggle it

```
var flipped = jQuery.data(elem,'flipped')//old value
flipped = !flipped;//toggle it
jQuery.data(elem,'flipped',flipped)//save it
```

I have updated example with that

http://jsfiddle.net/anuraguniyal/hnqB6/38/

Answer (score 4):

Use data

```
//read
$(yourElem).data("flipped")
//write
$(yourElem).data("flipped", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the design where there's only one triangle per canvas, you can set the flipped state on the canvas element itself using jQuery's `data()` method. So in your click event handler use `$(e.currentTarget).data('isflipped', 1);` to set state and `var isflipped = $(e.currentTarget).data('isflipped')` to get state.

If you don't use one triangle per canvas, you need to look at adding an intermediate drawing abstraction to get you out of immediate-mode canvas drawing into something more retained-mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a simple attribute 'flipped' on each canvas, but that's what Darek said on his comment (using classes instead) http://jsfiddle.net/hnqB6/55

Answer (score -1):

you can use data to attach the variable to element itself. I've updated your fiddle see it.

Comment: You should link to it in your answer.